# Question of the week #43

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Ok so apparently nobody was interested in the whole "42" thing, so we'll go back to the normal Question of the Week nominations:

Now we're into post #43 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've thought about doing a Review/How-To-Use of Hyper-V in Windows 8.  I asked & answered this question:

[How do I install and use Windows Virtual PC in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/472499/how-do-i-install-and-use-window-virtual-pc-in-windows-8)

And found/answered this one as well:

[Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access)

There are a few other features that I can go into detail like:

- Overview of Snapshots
- Requirements for being able to run it
- Talk about the [special case that Windows had to make](https://web.archive.org/web/20110923165930/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/07/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8.aspx) for Adding Wireless NIC's being accessible to the VM's

Answer (score 7):

[How much information can websites get about your browser/PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/470348/how-much-information-can-websites-get-about-your-browser-pc)

> Does anyone know of any other sites that will be able to get more information from the user passively like this? I'm not talking about port-sniffing or any kind of interaction from the user, just the info that a server can get from a 'dumb' visit.

Comment: I really like this idea, but I'm not exactly sure how I would test it.  Thinking that I might try to put together a quick Google App Engine and see what info I can get from visitors.